# Angular js $scope is Undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using angular js on one of my project. I'm very new to angular and the following error getting me more confused of using angular.

I have a js function

```
function ShowHideEditOptions(id) {
            var editOptions = document.getElementById("editOptions");
            editOptions.style.display = "block";
            selectedNodeId = id;

 InitializeMapForSelectedNode(); 

        }
```

I want to call the `InitializeMapForSelectedNode();`angular function in my `ShowHideEditOptions(id){}` function.

Is it possible???

when I'm doing this it gives me an error saying **$scope is undefined**

this is my angular controller in view

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);
    var selectedNodeId = "";
    app.controller("locationController", function ($compile, $scope, $log, $timeout) {    

$scope.InitializeMapForSelectedNode = function () {
                InitializeMapForSelectedNode($scope);
            }


    });
</script>
```

and the angular function is

```
function InitializeMapForSelectedNode($scope) {

    var locations = $scope.MeterList; // this is where the error occur

    .....
}
```

this function used previously binded $scope.MeterList variable.this is where fire bug detect the $scope is Undefined error.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but not recomeneded, unless you have a good reason.

Comment: You are not passing any value for the parameter `$scope` to the function `function InitializeMapForSelectedNode($scope)`, so it will be `undefined` yes.

Comment: could you replicate the same on plunker, http://plnkr.co

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling with `$scope`

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);
var selectedNodeId = "";
app.controller("locationController", function ($compile, $scope, $log, $timeout) {    

$scope.InitializeMapForSelectedNode = function () {
            $scope.InitializeMapForSelectedNode();
        }


});
```

Comment: He could also try with `while(true) { }`